The SE Chat WebSocket is down, returning status 520 (NS_ERROR_WEBSOCKET_CONNECTION_REFUSED)
On normal chat room pages on https://chat.stackexchange.com, the stock code in master-chat.js tries to establish a WebSocket connection to wss://chat.sockets.stackexchange.com/, which is currently returning a status 520, NS_ERROR_WEBSOCKET_CONNECTION_REFUSED (from Cloudflare). The chat software then falls back to doing HTTPS POSTs to /events every few seconds in order to see if there are any new messages. This is chat's normal fallback, which is used when a non-logged-in user is viewing a chat room. However, it's currently being used for everyone.
There's some investigation/discussion/confirmation that it's affecting multiple people in Charcoal HQ starting here.
I consider it likely that this has been happening for more than a day. Multiple people have reported a substantial increase in times a message is posted by someone else, but is not seen in their view of the chat room. That appears to be a symptom of the problem. I'm unsure when the issue started.
That chat is still largely functional is a testament to the design and effort put into it, many years ago now.

That chat is still largely functional is a testament to the design and effort put into it, many years ago now. Are you trying to please balpha?  ;)

He is pleased  Just want to point out that it should be completely functional, web sockets are completely optional (except messages may be slightly faster, but that shouldn't usually be noticeable in practice).

btw, in the past I may have retagged this as status-reproduced; see this post for why I am not. But the issue definitely exists, I'm investigating.

This seems like a perfect case for a [status-reproduced] tag. I don't see (or don't understand) the rationale in Slate's post for why it should be dropped, only the statement that all posts she found where it was currently used should be retagged. I didn't look at them, so I don't know why, but I would hazard a guess that was a dev was actively working on them and had reproduced the problem, but then got distracted or reprioritized and thus never got around to fixing it and retagging. That's not a problem with the tag. This situation is the exact kind of feedback we want from such a tag.

@CodyGray I can see the point though. If it's reproduced, then the interesting information is whether we're trying to fix it soon (status-planned) or later (status-deferred). Had the investigation taken me longer than it did, I probably would've gone with that.

Websockets are back in business. They are, as I mentioned in a comment, completely optional -- when we built the chat originally, we did it with AJAX polling only. The websocket standard hadn't stabilized yet, and so we went with the simplest thing that worked, and that was polling (and it worked perfectly, much to the surprise of industry veterans).
Anyway, we eventually added websockets, but polling has always been around and will transparently be activated whenever something isn't right with the websockets. And that was good today! In fact it has been good for a while -- as you pointed out  this didn't only break today, the issue has been increasing for some time.
Here's what seems to have been the problem: The Chat socket server has a buffer limit for incoming data. We don't really have any incoming data, websockets are only used for broadcasting, so the only thing that comes in is the initial connection request.
This limit was set to 2 KiB back in 2012 when we (mostly Marc) built the socket server.
And 2048 bytes should really be enough for everyone -- the browser doesn't send much more than "hey connect plz".
But over the past 12 years, requests seem to have grown. Your browser sends along its life story, Cloudflare probably adds a few headers of its own as well, and suddenly the socket server refuses to connect because the data is over 2 KiB, and it responds with this:
     
I have increased that buffer limit, and the number of requests to the AJAX route has steadily been trending down over the past 40 minutes since I deployed that change, so it seems to have done the trick.

Perfect answer! But I do wonder, if everything worked fine, why did you add Websockets support? What was the motivation, and doesn't it lead to extra expenses? (e.g. keeping another server up and alive)

Good question. I think it was a mix of things. Put side-by-side, it does feel a little more responsive to the user. It's also more efficient on our end -- even though we architected those polling requests to be very cheap, it's still more efficient to not have them at all and instead use an infrastructure that's more tailormade for this kind of thing (especially because we didn't have HTTP/2 yet). And let's not forget that it was also an interesting technical thing, and some of the things we learned were also applicable to adding realtime updates to the Q&A sites.
